# How to get the res of a form POST request in html?

Tags: html, node.js, forms

I have a form that send a POST request to my backend server in node js to create an account in a database. The request returns a message if there was an error during the process and I want to put this message in my page.

When the process is done the page only display a json file with the message returned.

html form

```html
<form action="/register" method='POST'>
            <div>
                <label for="username">username:</label>
                <input type="text" name='username' placeholder='username'/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="email">email:</label>
                <input type="text" name='email' placeholder='email'/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="password">password:</label>
                <input type="text" name='password' placeholder='password'/>
            </div>
            
            <input type='submit' value="Submit" />
        </form>
```

the node js request

```js
app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    const { username, email, password } = req.body;
    let user = await userModel.findOne({email});

    if (user) {
        return res.status(403).send({ message: "This email already has an account" });
    };

    const hashed = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

    user = new userModel({
        username,
        email,
        password: hashed,
    });

    await user.save();

    res.status(201).send({ message: "Account has ben created" });
});
```

My question is how can I get the response of the request easily to display it on the page?

Comment: Please edit your question and add in the code segment that demonstrates how you're returning the request. Then explain what problem you've encountered with passing that message to back to the form. It would also be helpful if you added a tag for node.js, since that is the language you're using in your request.

Comment: @devlincarnate I think its better now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your approach as follows:

1. Render the form using a template engine (ejs, etc) from the same server.
2. From the post request, rather than sending the json response, you can render the form template embedded with the success response or error messages (if any)

HTML Form (register.ejs)

```
<% if(locals.message) { %>
<div class="success-msg"><%= message %></div>
<% } %>

<% if(locals.error) { %>
<div class="error-msg"><%= error %></div>
<% } %>

<form action="/register" method='POST'>
    <div>
        <label for="username">username:</label>
        <input type="text" name='username' placeholder='username'/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">email:</label>
        <input type="text" name='email' placeholder='email'/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password">password:</label>
        <input type="text" name='password' placeholder='password'/>
    </div>
    
    <input type='submit' value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Node.js index

```
app.get('/register', async(req, res) => {
  res.render('register');
});

app.post('/register', async(req, res) => {

  const { username, email, password } = req.body;
    let user = await userModel.findOne({email});

    if (user) {
        return res.render('register', {error: 'This email already has an account'});
    };

    const hashed = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

    user = new userModel({
        username,
        email,
        password: hashed,
    });

    await user.save();

    return res.render('register', {message: 'Account has ben created'});

});
```

EDIT:- To implement this with react.js

Register.js

```
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [userName, setUserName] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState('');

    function submitForm(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        const bodyReq = {
            username: userName,
            email,
            password
        }
        dispatch( registerRequest(bodyReq, onRegisterSuccess, onRegisterError) );

    }

    function onRegisterError(err){
        setErrorMsg(err);
    }

    return (
        <>

            <div className="error-msg">{errorMsg}</div>
            
            <form onSubmit={e => submitForm(e)} method='POST'>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="username">username:</label>
                    <input value={userName} onChange={e => setUserName(e.target.value)} id="username" type="text" name='username' placeholder='username'/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="email">email:</label>
                    <input value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} type="text" name='email' id='email' placeholder='email'/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="password">password:</label>
                    <input value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} type="text" name='password' id='password' placeholder='password'/>
                </div>
                
                <input type='submit' value="Submit" />

            </form>

        </>        
    );
```

Server.js

```
app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    const { username, email, password } = req.body;
    let user = await userModel.findOne({email});

    if (user) {
        return res.status(403).json({ message: "This email already has an account" });
    };

    const hashed = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

    user = new userModel({
        username,
        email,
        password: hashed,
    });

    await user.save();

    return res.status(201).json({ message: "Account has ben created" });
});
```

Comment: Thanks its working well but is there the possibility to send this to a react page after?

Comment: @leoprosy, yes but in that case you don't need to use templates

You can store the error message(s) in a state and render that on dispatch, while from the server end, you need to return json response

Comment: @leoprosy, I have edited the code for react implementation